# PluginManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for Controlador

Tags: php, zend-framework, controller, zend-framework2

I was trying to create a plugin controller, like this:

```
Application\src\Application\Controller\Plugin\Controlador.php

namespace Application\Controller\Plugin;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\AbstractPluginManager;
use Biblioteca\Mvc\Db\TableGateway;

class Controlador extends AbstractPluginManager
{

   protected function getTable($table){

        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $dbAdapter = $sm->get('DbAdapter');
        $tableGateway = new TableGateway($dbAdapter, $table, new $table);
        $tableGateway->initialize();

        return $tableGateway;
    }

    protected function getService($service)
    {
        return $this->getServiceLocator()->get($service);
    }
}
```

And in my module.config.php i put this:

```
'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Application\Controller\Index' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController',

            'Controlador' => 'Application\Controller\Plugin\Controlador'
        ),
    ),
```

And in my indexController.php like this:

```
namespace Application\Controller;</br>


use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

use Biblioteca\ActionController;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController{


    public function indexAction()
    {

        $controlador = $this->Controlador();

        return new ViewModel(array(
            'posts' => $controlador->getTable('Application\Model\Post')->fetchAll()->toArray()
        ));
    }
}
```

and when i execute the code i get this message: "Zend\Mvc\Controller\PluginManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for Controlador"

someone can help me ?

Answer (score 1):

You are registering your plugin at the controllerManager which is responsible for creating controller instances. You need to define it at using 'controller_plugins' key in your module config.

```
return array(
    'controller_plugins' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Controlador' => 'Application\Controller\Plugin\Controlador'
        )
    )
);
```

Also you need to inherit `AbstractPlugin`. Now you are inheriting `AbstractPluginManager` which you'll use to create your own plugin manager.

```
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\AbstractPlugin;

class Controlador extends AbstractPlugin
{
```